# Android PedingIntent and setOnClickFillInIntent don't start Activity

Tags: android, android-appwidget, onupdate, android-remoteview

In my AppsSerive i load the installed packages with:

```
mApps = mContext.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(mainIntent, 0);
```

then i show an icon of the application and the label. I want to start the activity after klick on the icon or label.

I have set a pendingIntentTemplate in my WidgetProvider in onUpdate:

```
 Intent appsIntent = new Intent(context, AppsService.class);
   String packageName = appsIntent.getStringExtra(APP_ID);
   appsIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetIds[i]);
   PendingIntent appsPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, appsIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
   views.setPendingIntentTemplate(R.id.GridViewApps, appsPendingIntent);
```

And in the AppsService i have declared the setOnClickFillInIntent:

```
 Intent fillInIntent = new Intent();
    fillInIntent.setPackage(packageName);
    Bundle extras = new Bundle();
    fillInIntent.putExtras(extras);
    fillInIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
    rv.setOnClickFillInIntent(R.id.app_thumb, fillInIntent);
    rv.setOnClickFillInIntent(R.id.app_name, fillInIntent);
```

But when i click on the icon or label, it dosn't do anything.

The LogCat shows at any click on it the following:

```
07-24 11:51:06.153: E/DatabaseUtils(16583): Writing exception to parcel
07-24 11:51:06.153: E/DatabaseUtils(16583): java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: get/set setting for user asks to run as user -2 but is calling from user 0; this requires android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL
07-24 11:51:06.153: E/DatabaseUtils(16583):     at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleIncomingUser(ActivityManagerService.java:14643)
07-24 11:51:06.153: E/DatabaseUtils(16583):     at android.app.ActivityManager.handleIncomingUser(ActivityManager.java:2469)
07-24 11:51:06.153: E/DatabaseUtils(16583):     at com.android.providers.settings.SettingsProvider.call(SettingsProvider.java:688)
07-24 11:51:06.153: E/DatabaseUtils(16583):     at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.call(ContentProvider.java:325)
07-24 11:51:06.153: E/DatabaseUtils(16583):     at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:275)
07-24 11:51:06.153: E/DatabaseUtils(16583):     at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:404)
07-24 11:51:06.153: E/DatabaseUtils(16583):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)


07-24 11:51:06.384: W/ActivityManager(16583): destPackageName = null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have identified three potential sources of the problem:

1. You need to update your `AppWidgetManager` with `updateAppWidget(...);` after setting the click listeners
2. I am not sure if you are using `setOnClickFillInIntent()` correctly. Are you using it intentionally and do you know what it does? You only really need it if your widget contains a collection like a `ListView`. If it doesn't use `setOnClickPendingIntent()`.
3. Could the error be here: `fillInIntent.setPackage(packageName);`? I think `packageName` might be `null`!

Comment: Hi Xaver, thanks, i update it after the click Listener:

`appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);`

Yes, the apps are listed in a gridView.

Comment: Thank You Xaver, that is the Problem:
`String packageName = mApps.get(position).activityInfo.packageName;`